# Does the LinkedIn API cover University pages?

Tags: linkedin-api

Title pretty much says it all. Is there any way to access the feed/ updates of a university page on LinkedIn?

The only mention of university on their developer site is their Alumni widget.

Answer (score 2):

In one word: No.

With all the currently available endpoints of the API, there seems to be no endpoint for University pages. You can check all the available endpoints [here](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin).

I tried accessing the University page by using the Company page endpoint and some random University's id, and as expected, it does not work. You can test it on your own at the link mentioned above.

So, either the University page needs to be changed to a Company page or there is no scope from the available API to get the data.

Even if the page is a company page, you will need the admin permission to access it. You can check all the details related to company page [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages).

Comment: Hi @Jagrut. Thanks for your answer. If you don't own a University page, you can't prove that the API will or will not work. The same applies to the API documentation. I was really looking for this information from an official source. Have you found anythings in that direction?

Comment: @ViniciusMiana In their official documentation they have not mentioned anything. At least, I was not able to find it.